# How can I use optional chaining in object data when I use JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm taking singlePost data from Redux and making it into an array using Object.keys.

However, when rendering is in progress, singlePost is received late, so when I try to console.log, null is recorded at first and then the correct data comes in.

So this error is printed.

> Cannot convert undefined or null to object

this is my code

```
  const Explain = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const {singlePost} = useSelector((state) => state.post);

  console.log("singlePost:",singlePost);

  // singlePost: null    first recorded

  // singlePost:

  // singlePost = {
  //   User: {
  //     id: 3,
  //     nickname: "bill",
  //   },
  //   content1: "number1",
  //   content2: "number2",         second recorded
  //   content3: "bye",
  //   content4: "empty",
  //   content5: "empty",
  //   content6: "empty",
  //   content7: "empty",
  //   content8: "number3",
  //   content9: "empty",
  //   content10: "empty",
  // };   


  const contentOnly = Object.keys(singlePost)
  
  return (
  
  );
};

export default Explain;
```

How can I fix this error? Can I use optional chaining in object?

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need for optional chaining. [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is only useful when accessing a property of a possibly-null object, and you're calling a function with the object as an argument.

You might be thinking of [the nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), which gives you a different value if the one under inspection is null or undefined, which you could possibly use here via:

```
const contentOnly = Object.keys(singlePost ?? {});
```

However, I'd say that's a rather roundabout way of getting an empty array. I'd just use [a ternary, or conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
const contentOnly = singlePost == null ? [] : Object.keys(singlePost);
```

This tells readers exactly what they're going to get, especially if you set `singlePost` to null by default.

Answer (score 2):

you can check the `typeof` the variable and whether it's null or not as below:

```
const contentOnly = (typeof singlePost === 'object' && singlePost !== null) ? Object.keys(singlePost): []
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can check if singlePost is defined:

```
const contentOnly = Object.keys(singlePost || {})
// or
if(singlePost && typeof singlePost == 'object') {...do something}
```

If your need optional chaining(according to question title). You can do something like this

```
singlePost && singlePost.content1
// or with new syntax
singlePost?.content1
```

Pay attention - the new syntax is not supported by all environments